# ggplot Dynamic Shape and Size change of lines on graph Creates Second Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the shape and size of a points on 2 lines and I can do that but a second legend appears.

When you run this code you will see 2 legends. I only want the "variable" legend.

```
library("ggplot2")
MyData<-data.frame(time= c(1,2,3,1,2,3), value = c(.4,.6,.7,.1,.2,.3), variable =         c("company a","company a","company a","company b","company b","company b")      )
MyData$pointsize <- ifelse(MyData$time==2, 5, 1)
MyData$shape <- ifelse(MyData$time==2, 4, 7)
MyData
ggplot(MyData, aes( x = time,  y=value,colour=variable, group= variable)  )   +           geom_line()   + geom_point(aes(shape = MyData$pointsize,size = MyData$pointsize) )+
  scale_shape_identity()
```

How do I remove the legend for  Mydata$PointSize?

Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you should know that you should really never be specifying columns like `Mydata$PointSize` inside of `aes`. You should only be mapping to the column name, `pointsize`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `guide=FALSE` inside the `scale_size_continuous()` to remove this legend.

```
+scale_size_continuous(guide=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the answer is to do:
........ +  scale_shape_identity(guide="none")+scale_size_identity(guide="none")

Comment: If you are using `scale_size_identity()` then there is no need for argument `guide="none"` because it is default value. Also identity scales are used only if the values should be used directly as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `guides` option. Use the aesthetics that appear as legend as parameter and set them to `FALSE`.

`guides(colour=FALSE)` would remove the one legend, `guides(size=FALSE)` the other one and `guides(colour=FALSE, size=FALSE)` would remove both.

```
library("ggplot2")
MyData<-data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                   value=c(.4,.6,.7,.1,.2,.3), 
                   variable=c("company a","company a","company a","company b","company b","company b"))
MyData$pointsize <- ifelse(MyData$time==2, 5, 1)
MyData$shape <- ifelse(MyData$time==2, 4, 7)
MyData
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=time, y=value,colour=variable, group=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=MyData$pointsize, size=MyData$pointsize)) +
  scale_shape_identity() + 
  guides(colour=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

*Note: The following is an old answer, which only refers to the initial question that was revised in between! It does no longer apply to the above question...*
Due to the mapping (aesthetics), you have two groups, thus all "time", "shape" and "pointsize" values appear twice (one time for each group). So you have 3 values for each group (line). However, you supply 6 values to geom_point, as you don't specify aesthetics. The data mapping for the plot using aes and the data used for geom_point have different lengths. A solution would be:

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=time, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable))+geom_line()+ geom_point(aes(shape=factor(shape), size=pointsize))
```

Comment: You're right - I'm not sure whether I'm still in the right thread, I thought I read something about "error length aesthetics"...

Comment: If these are the revisions: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22994121/revisions my answer refers to the initial question...